# Animated Figure (image) within a class

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to create an animated image.

I found some code that works very well for doing it using functions,

But when I try to write the exact same code not using functions but using class(es), it doesn't work anymore.

I've been struggling for hours and am not able to find any answer on the internet. I'm sure it musn't be that difficult but I really don't understand what part of my code is wrong.

Thank you for help.

## Version 1 (function type) : Works

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.animation import TimedAnimation

fig = plt.figure()


def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)

myfig = f(x, y)

im = plt.imshow(myfig, animated=True)


def updatefig(*args):
    global x, y
    x += np.pi / 15.
    y += np.pi / 20.
    im.set_array(f(x, y))
    return im,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, interval=50, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

## Version 2 (class type) : Doesn't work

```py
class AnimatedFigure:

    def __init__(self):

        self.fig = plt.figure()

        self.x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120)
        self.y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)

        self.f()

        self.im = plt.imshow(self.data, animated=True)

        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.updatefig, interval=50, blit=True)

    def f(self):
        self.data = np.sin(self.x) + np.cos(self.y)

    def updatefig(self, *args):
        self.x += np.pi / 15.
        self.y += np.pi / 20.
        self.f()
        self.im.set_array(self.data)

AF = AnimatedFigure()
```

Comment: You don't call `plt.show()` in your second version, so nothing actually gets shown. I think there's another error relating to how `animation.FuncAnimation()` requires it's second argument to return something, but I couldn't figure out how to fix it without basically reverting to your functional case.